# PowerBI - Find sum of column in last 5 occurrences per group

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data which looks like this. I have multiple Areas, Rooms and Grades which record "Value" per occurrence date. This date need not be every day and can be at random.

[image]

What I want to achieve is calculate sum of "Value" in the last 5 occurrences for each recorded date. This new calculation would be per Area, Room and Grade.

How I approached this issue was to rank the dates per Area, Room and Grade. However, I am stuck with how to move ahead with calculating the sum for last 5 ranks. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using the date column as row values or an axis, this will give you the sum of value for the last 5 occurences:

```
SUMX(TOPN(5,'MyTable','MyTable'[Date],DESC), [Measure])
```

Comment: Your answer is missing the measure in the SUMX. It should be `SUMX( TOPN( 5, 'MyTable', 'MyTable'[Date], DESC ), [Measure] )`